# how to ensure a user input contains at least one uppercase, lowercase, symbol, and number in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, loops

I want to ensure that a password a user enters is at least 7 characters long and has at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one symbol. 
The code seems to pass through the if loop until the symbol argument where it gets stuck.

```
puts "Please enter your desired password: "
password = []
pass_clear = ()
while pass_clear == (nil) do
  password = gets.to_s.chomp

  if password.length < 7
    puts "Your password must contain at least seven characters."
  elsif password.count("a-z") == password.length
    puts "Your password must contain at least one uppercase character."
  elsif password.count("A-Z") == password.length
    puts "Your password must contain at least one lowercase character."
  elsif password.count("!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=") < 1
    puts "Your password must contain at least one symbol."
  elsif password.count("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9") < 1
    puts "Your password must contain at least one number."
  else
    puts "Thank you, your account is complete."
    pass_clear == 1
  end

end
```

This is the output:

```
Please enter your desired password:
frank
Your password must contain at least seven characters.
Please enter your desired password: 
frankie
Your password must contain at least one uppercase character.
Please enter your desired password: 
Frankie
Your password must contain at least one symbol.
Please enter your desired password: 
Frankie$
Your password must contain at least one symbol.
Please enter your desired password:
```

And it continues looping through the symbol stage regardless of how many symbols there are.
How can I ensure these symbols are recognized so the loop can finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quoting each of the symbols which is incorrect. You also have to escape the - and ^ characters

```
password.count("!@#$%\\^&*()_\\-+=")
```

works for me in this example.

You'll also need to use a range for your numbers like:

```
password.count("0-9")
```

The - character is used for the ranges like "a-z" so it has to be escaped, the carat ^ is used to negate a count so:

password.count("^a-z")

would return a count of everything that wasn't in the range of a-z.

This can come in handy as you may want to prevent certain characters from being in your password strings. You could do something like:

```
password.count("^a-zA-Z!@#$%\\^&*()_\\-+=0-9)
```

This would count any other characters outside what you've defined so you would want to get a zero return value to know they didn't use any forbidden characters.

Some further clarification on ranges in `count()`. The term "range" should not be confused with the Ruby class "Range". The class of Range uses ".." or "..." for the intervening items. In the `count()` method the range being considered is the ASCII range from the first character's ASCII number to the second character's ASCII number. That's why in my original typo of `A-z` it was counting ASCII 65 ("A") to ASCII 122 ("z") which happens to include the characters ASCII 92 to 96 which are not letters but  \  ]  ^  _   `

Comment: That fixes it, thanks. Why do - and ^ require escape? I'm a bit new so it's my first run in with that.

Comment: There was a typo in my last line of code, the range `"A-z"` should have been `"A-Z"`. That typo had some weird effects because there are some characters like `[` and `]` between `"A-z"`

Comment: Also don't forget to prevent spaces with something like `password.count(" ")` and fail if you return more than zero.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a regex that contains four positive lookaheads, all of which operate from the beginning of the string.

```
R = /
    (?=.*\p{Ll})                                # match lowercase letter
    (?=.*\p{Lu})                                # match uppercase letter
    (?=.*\d)                                    # match digit
    (?=.*[#{Regexp.escape("!@#$%^&*(,)_+=-")}]) # match special char 
    /x                                          # free-spacing regex def mode

def password_ok?(str)
  str.match?(R)
end

password_ok? "aA1#" #=> true
password_ok? "A1#"  #=> false
password_ok? "a1#"  #=> false 
password_ok? "aA#"  #=> false
password_ok? "aA1"  #=> false
```